# GWT Table with headers on the left

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I was wondering if it's possible to create a CellTable with the headers on the side instead of on top.
Or what would be a good way to show data in this way?

Example:

```
------------------------------------------
- Name      -   My name                  -
------------------------------------------
- Surname   -   My surname               -
------------------------------------------
- Email     -   name.surname@mail.com    -
------------------------------------------
```

I could do it using simple panels but in this case I don't know how to use a data provider.

Update: SmartGWT provides this functionality with DetailViewer, but I cannot use SmartGWT.

Comment: I don't work with SmartGWT but AFAIK DetailViewer only displays details of some row, isn't it? In this case I don't think this is what you need

Comment: @Miroslav it's exactly what I need.
I have a table showing the list of records and on selecting one I want to show the details.

Comment: Then try to look at the CellList example http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList You can do the similar thing also with CellTable. Is this what you need?

Comment: I need something like the "Contact Info" form, but styled like a table and not editable.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend AbstractCellTableBuilder

```
MyTableBuilder extends AbstractCellTableBuilder<T>
```

and override

```
protected void buildRowImpl()
```

Then add a style to each first td element so it looks like a header, etc... The buildRowImpl() gives you control about how each row is built. It's going to be a bit tricky to manipulate your model but you should be able to see through it.

Then give the table builder to your cell table as follows and call your data provider to refresh the display.

```
 myCellTable.setTableBuilder(new MyTableBuilder());
```

Comment: Unfortunately the version of GWT (2.4) we're using does not support AbstractCellTableBuilder...